# Is there an onPause in ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer, onpause, android-actionbaractivity

I was following Android tutorials from mybringback and he was using his created class and it was, by default, extended to use Activity and since that video was made a while ago, I'm guessing that ActionBarActivity wasn't available then.

However in the tutorial he uses super.onPause in his media file video, which is not available in the override methods for ActionBarActivity, so I was wondering, if there was another way for me to do the same thing, if onPause would be called something else in ActionBarActivity, or if I should just change ActionBarActivity to Activity instead.

Thanks!

Comment: `onPause()` is available in `ActionBarActivity`. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: @323go I can't see it when i right click >Source > Override/Implement Methods... .

Comment: Its under FragmentActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse if you want to use Source->Override/Implement Methods, to generate the onPause method, you need to look under the FragmentActivity expansion,  since ActionBarActivity is a subclass of FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBarActivity` subclasses `FragmentActivity`

`FragmentActivity` subclasses `Activity`

`Activity` contains method `onPause()`

Therefore, yes! There is an `onPause()` method in `ActionBarActivity`

You should really learn to use documentation and not rely on override implement methods feature in Eclipse https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html